# Firestore: Return only documents where rule condition is met

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I get a `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.` error when I try to retrieve all documents with a specific property from a collection. To be clear, this is on the Firestore Rules level, not application level - I'm not struggling with `.where()` queries.

My firebase rules currently look as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /projects/{project} {
      allow read: if resource.data.visible == true; // This condition seems to be the problem child
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

I've confirmed that `resource.data.visible == true` is what's causing the issue by swapping it out for `request.auth != null`, in which case no errors are thrown and it returns all documents.

Here's a screenshot of one of my documents:

[image]

The other censored document has its `visible` property set to `false`.

And here's my (JavaScript) code that I use to access Firestore:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('projects').onSnapshot(snap => {
  console.log('snap:', snap);
}, err => {
  console.error(err); // Here's where the error gets thrown
});
```

Let me know if I need to include any additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to use a Firestore security rule as a filter, but [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  The query is evaluated against its potential result set, and if it could possibly return documents that the client does not have permission to read, the entire query will fail.

However, you can solve this by also adding the necessary constraint to your query.  For example (I have not tested this exact code, but this should be close to what you need):

```
firebase.firestore().collection('projects').where("visible", "==", true).onSnapshot()
```

If you need more details, basically this exact example (doing a query with a security rule restricted by a field on the document that defines its visibility) is in [the security rules documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_a_field).

Answer (score 1):

Firebase security rules don't filter your data on their own. Instead they merely check that any operations your application executes are allowed according to the rules.

Since your code tries to read all `projects`, the rules check if that is allowed. And since the rules specify that users can only read projects that are visible, the read for all projects is rejected.

When you want to allow partial access to the data in a collection, you'll need to write both rules and code to make this work. In your case, you'll want to filter your code too.

```
firebase.firestore().collection('projects').where('visible', '=', true)
```